# sqlitedatabase update where clauses

Tags: android-sqlite

i am getting a string category and address name from other class
what i need is to update categories table with specific address_id which is foreign key to address table. and address table contains a address_name. 
So I am getting address_name from other class and i want to update categories table which specific address_id with given address_name and change its categories name to string category.

this is code that i have tried but it did not work, it does not gives error in android studio but it does not actually updates in the database.

```
public void updateData(String categories, String positionName){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("categories_name", categories);
    Log.d(TAG, "updateData: " + categories );
    database.update("categories", contentValues, "address_id = ?", new String[]{"(SELECT address_id FROM address WHERE address_name = " + positionName + ")"});
```

this is my address table

```
CREATE TABLE "address" (
"address_id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"address_name"  TEXT UNIQUE,
"lat"   BLOB NOT NULL,
"lng"   BLOB NOT NULL,
"date"  NUMERIC);
```

and this is my categories table

```
CREATE TABLE "categories" (
"Categories_id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"categories_name"   TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'place' CHECK(categories_name in ('place','home','work')),
"address_id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
FOREIGN KEY("address_id") REFERENCES "address"("address_id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

public class EditProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button searchBtn;
EditText userName_editText;
EditText password_editText;
EditText dob_editText;
RadioGroup genderRadioGroup;
RadioButton genderRadioBtn;
Button editBtn;
Button deleteBtn;
Intent intent;
DBHandler dbHandler;

public static final String USERID_EDITPROFILE = "userID";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

    searchBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.editprof_searchbtn);
    userName_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editprof_userName);
    password_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editprof_password);
    dob_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editprof_dob);
    genderRadioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.editprof_radiogroup);
    editBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.editprof_editbtn);
    deleteBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.editprof_deletebtn);
    intent = getIntent();


    dbHandler = new DBHandler(EditProfile.this);

    setUserDetails();

    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String username = userName_editText.getText().toString();

            if(username == null){
                Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Please enter username to delete your profile",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                UserProfile.Users users = dbHandler.readAllInfor(username);

                if(users == null){
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"No profile found from this username, please enter valid username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    dbHandler.deleteInfo(username);
                    Intent redirectintent_home = new Intent("com.modelpaper.mad.it17121002.Home");
                    startActivity(redirectintent_home);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String userID_String = intent.getStringExtra(Home.USERID);
            if(userID_String == null){
                Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Error!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent redirectintent_home =  new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
                startActivity(redirectintent_home);
            }
            int userID = Integer.parseInt(userID_String);

            String username = userName_editText.getText().toString();
            String password = password_editText.getText().toString();
            String dob = dob_editText.getText().toString();
            int selectedGender = genderRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            genderRadioBtn = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedGender);
            String gender = genderRadioBtn.getText().toString();

            UserProfile.Users users = UserProfile.getProfile().getUser();
            users.setUsername(username);
            users.setPassword(password);
            users.setDob(dob);
            users.setGender(gender);
            users.setId(userID);

            dbHandler.updateInfor(users);
            Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Updated Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent redirectintent_home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
            startActivity(redirectintent_home);
        }
    });

    searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           String username = userName_editText.getText().toString();
           if (username == null){
               Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Please enter a username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           else{
               UserProfile.Users users_search = dbHandler.readAllInfor(username);


               if(users_search == null){
                   Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Please enter a valid username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               else{
                   userName_editText.setText(users_search.getUsername());
                   password_editText.setText(users_search.getPassword());
                   dob_editText.setText(users_search.getDob());
                   int id = users_search.getId();
                   Intent redirectintent = new Intent("com.modelpaper.mad.it17121002.EditProfile");
                   redirectintent.putExtra(USERID_EDITPROFILE,Integer.toString(id));
                   startActivity(redirectintent);
               }
           }
        }
    });


}

public void setUserDetails(){

    String userID_String = intent.getStringExtra(Home.USERID);
    if(userID_String == null){
        Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Error!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent redirectintent_home = new Intent("com.modelpaper.mad.it17121002.Home");
        startActivity(redirectintent_home);
    }
    int userID = Integer.parseInt(userID_String);
    UserProfile.Users users = dbHandler.readAllInfor(userID);
    userName_editText.setText(users.getUsername());
    password_editText.setText(users.getPassword());
    dob_editText.setText(users.getDob());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**ProfileMangement**

```
public class ProfileManagement extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText username_editText;
    EditText password_editText;
    EditText dob_editText;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton gender_radioBtn;
    Button saveProfBtn;

    public final static String USERID_PROFILEMGMT = "userID";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_management);

        username_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.profmgmt_userName);
        password_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.profmgmt_password);
        dob_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.profmgmt_dob);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.profmgmt_radiogroup);
        saveProfBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.profmgmt_btn);
        final DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(ProfileManagement.this);

        saveProfBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String username = username_editText.getText().toString();
                String password = password_editText.getText().toString();
                String dob = dob_editText.getText().toString();
                int selectedGender = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                gender_radioBtn = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedGender);
                String gender = gender_radioBtn.getText().toString();

                UserProfile.Users users = UserProfile.getProfile().getUser();
                users.setUsername(username);
                users.setPassword(password);
                users.setDob(dob);
                users.setGender(gender);
                boolean result = dbHandler.addInfo(users);

                if(result ==  true){
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileManagement.this,"Successfully added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    UserProfile.Users newusers = dbHandler.readAllInfor(username);
                    int userID = newusers.getId();
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.modelpaper.mad.it17121002.EditProfile");
                    intent.putExtra(USERID_PROFILEMGMT,Integer.toString(userID));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*********db hander*******************

/**
 * Created by Suraj on 10/6/2018.
 */

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public DBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, "user_db", null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE "+UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME +"( "+UserProfile.Users.COL_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT 
    ,"+UserProfile.Users.COL_USERNAME+" TEXT UNIQUE," +
            UserProfile.Users.COL_PASSWORD +" TEXT, "+UserProfile.Users.COL_GENDER +" TEXT, "+UserProfile.Users.COL_DOB +" TEXT"+")";

    Log.d("createQuery",createQuery);

    try {
        db.execSQL(createQuery);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

   //onUpgardeMethod// String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE "+UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME +"( "+UserProfile.Users.COL_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT 
    ,"+UserProfile.Users.COL_USERNAME+" TEXT," +
            UserProfile.Users.COL_PASSWORD +" TEXT, "+UserProfile.Users.COL_GENDER +" TEXT, "+UserProfile.Users.COL_DOB+" TEXT"+")";

    Log.d("createQuery",createQuery);

    try {
        db.execSQL(createQuery);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

public boolean addInfo(UserProfile.Users users){

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO "+UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME+"("+UserProfile.Users.COL_USERNAME+","+UserProfile.Users.COL_PASSWORD+",
    "+UserProfile.Users.COL_GENDER+","+
            UserProfile.Users.COL_DOB+") VALUES('"+users.getUsername()+"','"+users.getPassword()+"','"+users.getGender()+"','"+users.getDob()+"')";

    Log.d("insertQuery",insertQuery);

    try {
        db.execSQL(insertQuery);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());
    }

    db.close();
    return false;
}

public boolean updateInfor(UserProfile.Users users){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    String username = users.getUsername();
    String password = users.getPassword();
    String dob = users.getDob();
    String gender = users.getGender();
    int id = users.getId();
    values.put(UserProfile.Users.COL_DOB,dob);
    values.put(UserProfile.Users.COL_GENDER,gender);
    values.put(UserProfile.Users.COL_PASSWORD,password);
    values.put(UserProfile.Users.COL_USERNAME,username);

    int result = db.update(UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME,values,UserProfile.Users.COL_ID+" = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

    if(result >0)
        return true;

    return false;
}


public ArrayList<UserProfile.Users> readAllInfor(){

    ArrayList<UserProfile.Users> userList = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String readAllQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(readAllQuery,null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            UserProfile.Users users = UserProfile.getProfile().getUser();

            users.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            users.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
            users.setPassword(cursor.getString(2));
            users.setGender(cursor.getString(3));
            users.setDob(cursor.getString(4));

            userList.add(users);

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return userList;

}

public UserProfile.Users readAllInfor(String userName){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String readSingleQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+ UserProfile.Users.COL_USERNAME + " =  '"+ userName+"'";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(readSingleQuery,null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

        UserProfile.Users users = UserProfile.getProfile().getUser();

        users.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        users.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
        users.setPassword(cursor.getString(2));
        users.setGender(cursor.getString(3));
        users.setDob(cursor.getString(4));

        return users;
    }

   return null;
}

public UserProfile.Users readAllInfor(int id){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String readSingleQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+ UserProfile.Users.COL_ID + " =  '"+ id+"'";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(readSingleQuery,null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

        UserProfile.Users users = UserProfile.getProfile().getUser();

        users.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        users.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
        users.setPassword(cursor.getString(2));
        users.setGender(cursor.getString(3));
        users.setDob(cursor.getString(4));

        return users;
    }

    return null;
}



public void deleteInfo(String username){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM "+ UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+ UserProfile.Users.COL_USERNAME +" = '"+ username +"' ";
    Log.d("deleteQuery ",deleteQuery);
    db.execSQL(deleteQuery);
    db.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

public final class UserProfile {

```
private UserProfile(){

}

public static UserProfile getProfile(){

    UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
    return userProfile;
}
class Users implements BaseColumn{

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "UserInfo";
    public static final String COL_ID = "_ID";
    public static final String COL_USERNAME  = "userName ";
    public static final String COL_DOB = "dateOfBirth";
    public static final String COL_GENDER = "Gender";
    public static final String COL_PASSWORD = "Password";

    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String dob;
    private String gender;
    private String password;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}

public Users getUser(){
    Users users = new Users();

    return users;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText username_editText;
EditText password_editText;
Button loginbtn;
Button registerbtn;

public static final String USERID = "userID";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    username_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.home_userName);
    password_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.home_password);
    loginbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home_loginBtn);
    registerbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home_registerBtn);
    final DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(Home.this);

    registerbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent("com.modelpaper.mad.it17121002.ProfileManagement");
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String userName = username_editText.getText().toString();
            String password = password_editText.getText().toString();

           if(userName == null){
               Toast.makeText(Home.this,"Login Unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           else{
               UserProfile.Users users = dbHandler.readAllInfor(userName);

               if(users == null){
                   Toast.makeText(Home.this,"Invalid username or password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

               else{
                   int userID = users.getId();
                   Intent editProfIntent = new Intent("com.modelpaper.mad.it17121002.EditProfile");
                   editProfIntent.putExtra(USERID,Integer.toString(userID));
                   startActivity(editProfIntent);

               }
           }
        }
    });
}
```

}